# PowerShell-WPF - Datagrid background colour for cell based on value

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm Woking on WPF tool based on Powershell to get disk information from multiple servers where I need to set background colour to a specific cell form Percentfree columns as RED if disk is having less than 10% free space and Orange if between 10-15 % free space. after going through couple for blogs/article, somehow I managed to get expected results except still struggling to set background colour for multiple values or range of values.

any help in this would be appreciated. Thanks..!

```
    <DataGrid Name="diskstatus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,65,0,10" Width="739" GridLinesVisibility="None" AlternatingRowBackground="Lightgray" AlternationCount="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server Name" Binding="{Binding ServerName}" Width="130"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Csize (GB)" Binding="{Binding Csize}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cfree (GB)" Binding="{Binding Cfree}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="CPercentfree" Binding="{Binding CPercentfree}" Width="100">
              <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                     <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="Text" Value="5">
                       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                       </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
           </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dsize (GB)" Binding="{Binding Dsize}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dfree (GB)" Binding="{Binding Dfree}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DPercentfree" Binding="{Binding DPercentfree}" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Powershell Function to get disk info:

```
Function Getdiskinfo()
{
 $dsk=@()
 $importcsv= Import-Csv -Path $TPAcsvfile
 $Getservers = $importcsv.servername
 foreach ($CompName in $Getservers)
 {

$cdrivespace= Get-WMIObject Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $CompName |  ?{$_.DeviceID -eq 'C:'} | Select @{Name=‘cTotalSize’;Expression={[int]($_.Size / 1gb)}},`
@{Name=‘cFreeSpace’;Expression={[int]($_.FreeSpace / 1gb)}}, @{Name=‘cPercentFree’;Expression={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size,2)*100}}


$ddrivespace= Get-WMIObject Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $CompName |  ?{$_.DeviceID -eq 'D:'} | Select @{Name=‘dTotalSize’;Expression={[int]($_.Size / 1gb)}},`
@{Name=‘dFreeSpace’;Expression={[int]($_.FreeSpace / 1gb)}}, @{Name=‘dPercentFree’;Expression={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size,2)*100}}


     $diskinfo = New-Object psobject
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "ServerName" -value $CompName
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "cSize" -value $cdrivespace.cTotalSize
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "cFree" -value $cdrivespace.cFreeSpace
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "cPercentfree" -value $cdrivespace.cPercentFree
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "DSize" -value $ddrivespace.dTotalSize
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "DFree" -value $ddrivespace.dFreeSpace
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "DPercentfree" -value $ddrivespace.dPercentFree
     $diskstatus.addchild($diskinfo) 
     $dsk +=$diskinfo

 } Return, $dsk
}
```

Comment: Uhm... so where is the powershell part of what you tried so far?

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for reply...will little work somehow I managed to get cell background colour with single value using DataGrid view however still struggling to expected results to multiple values for the same column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the limitations of `Powershell-WPF` but basically, you should create a Converter that is translating from `CPercentfree` to an aggregate range identifier.

For example, lets use a converter with the following translations:

```
CPercentfree > 15:
    Result = 0
CPercentfree >= 10:
    Result = 1
Otherwise (lower than 10)
    Result = 2
```

In C# the converter would look similar to the following, I hope you can translate it for yourself:

```
public class WarningLevelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int v = value as Nullable<int> ?? System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        if (v > 15)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (v >= 10)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then create the converter somewhere in resources (assuming `local` is `xmlns` of the project namespace)

```
<local:WarningLevelConverter x:Key="cWarningLevel"/>
```

And use it with some data triggers:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="CPercentfree" Binding="{Binding CPercentfree}" Width="100">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CPercentfree,Converter={StaticResource cWarningLevel}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CPercentfree,Converter={StaticResource cWarningLevel}}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Note I'm not 100% sure about the DataContext on the `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CPercentfree,Converter={StaticResource cWarningLevel}}"` part. You may have to change it to `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cWarningLevel}}"` eventually.